# Не могу понять почему не работает require в nodejs

Tags: node.js

Долго с этим мучилась, грешила на ОС, пробовала тот же трюк на Linux у пред установкой параметров через scripts но та же ошибка, не могу понять где косанула.

файл 1: 
index.js

```
const {Server} = require('http');
const fbserver = require('fbserver'); 
const server = new Server(fbserver);
server.listen(8000);
```

файл 2:
/utils/fbserver.js

```
let i = 10;
module.exports = (req, res) => { 
    i++;
    res.end(i.toString());
};
```

package.json имеет инструкция скрипта для запуске через консоль: `nmp start`

```
  "scripts": {
  "start": "set NODE_PATH=./utils && node index.js"
  },
```

Вроде бы все установила правильно, но упорно не хочет находить модуль fbserver.js (.

Ответ консоли:

```
D:\ndjs\01>npm start

> node-materials@1.0.0 start D:\ndjs\01
> set NODE_PATH=./utils && node index.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fbserver'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\ndjs\01\index.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ann\\AppData\
\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v10.0.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.0.5
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! node-materials@1.0.0 start: `set NODE_PATH=./utils && node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-materials@1.0.0 start script 'set NODE_PATH=./utils
&& node index.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-materials packag
e,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     set NODE_PATH=./utils && node index.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs node-materials
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-materials
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to in
stall?

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\ndjs\01\npm-debug.log
```

запись из npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Ann\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@4.0.5
3 info using node@v10.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle node-materials@1.0.0~prestart: node-materials@1.0.0
6 silly lifecycle node-materials@1.0.0~prestart: no script for prestart, continuing
7 info lifecycle node-materials@1.0.0~start: node-materials@1.0.0
8 verbose lifecycle node-materials@1.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
9 verbose lifecycle node-materials@1.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;D:\ndjs\01\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\Broadcom 802.11\Driver;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm
10 verbose lifecycle node-materials@1.0.0~start: CWD: D:\ndjs\01
11 silly lifecycle node-materials@1.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'set NODE_PATH=./utils && node index.js' ]
12 silly lifecycle node-materials@1.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
13 info lifecycle node-materials@1.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
14 verbose stack Error: node-materials@1.0.0 start: `set NODE_PATH=./utils && node index.js`
14 verbose stack Exit status 1
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
14 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Ann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
14 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
14 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:947:16)
14 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:236:5)
15 verbose pkgid node-materials@1.0.0
16 verbose cwd D:\ndjs\01
17 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
18 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Ann\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
19 error node v10.0.0
20 error npm  v4.0.5
21 error code ELIFECYCLE
22 error node-materials@1.0.0 start: `set NODE_PATH=./utils && node index.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the node-materials@1.0.0 start script 'set NODE_PATH=./utils && node index.js'.
23 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
23 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-materials package,
23 error not with npm itself.
23 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
23 error     set NODE_PATH=./utils && node index.js
23 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
23 error     npm bugs node-materials
23 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
23 error     npm owner ls node-materials
23 error There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: `require` понятия не имеет, что этот Ваш `fbserver.js` надо искать в `utils`, ему это надо указать: `require('./utils/fbserver.js')`.

Comment: @Yaant, ответы - в ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`require`, если переданное имя модуля не начинается с `/`, `./` или `../`, ищет этот модуль в каталогах `node_modules`, начиная с текущего, и далее вверх до корня файловой системы. Соответственно, ни о каком каталоге `utils` `require` понятия не имеет. Нестандартные пути надо указывать явным образом: `require('./utils/fbserver.js')`.

Также можно (но очень не рекомендуется) использовать переменную окружения `NODE_PATH` (что Вы, судя по приведенному коду, и пытались сделать), но в этом случае в `NODE_PATH` надо указывать **абсолютные** пути к каталогам, у Вас же указан относительный.

Подробнее можно почитать в [документации](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders).